# How I could use media query for hovering an element?

Tags: html, css

My problem is that when I try to use media query for hovering an element, such as a clickable link in the nav bar, it is still working with that new set rules but but it also applies the rules given in the normal broswer.

For example:

```
nav ul li a:hover{
border:0;
background-color:green;
color:yellow;
border-radius: 26px;
padding: 60px 10px;
}  
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
nav ul li:hover{
background-color: black;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 20px;
}
}
```

Let me show you result:
[image]

So now as you can see, it combines two rules, but all what I expect is that the links from the nav only use the rule given in @media  block when the browser size is less 700px. Are there any helps, please, I am very appreciated!

Comment: It because you apply hover affect on `li` instead of `a` tag. set hover affect in `nav ul li a:hover{}` in media query

Answer (score 1):

Keep the same selector.
Either have "a:hover" or "li:hover a" in both cases.

Edit:
Right now on max width 600px you will have both rules applied, they don't override eachother.

Answer (score 1):

### Target The Same Elements on Every Media Query

Target the same elements on every media query to get the result you are after.

```
 nav ul li a:hover {
  border:0;
  background-color:green;
  color:yellow;
  border-radius: 26px;
  padding: 60px 10px;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  nav ul li a:hover {
   background-color: black;
   width: 100%;
   border-radius: 20px;
 }
}
```